# Yellowstone tablet camera sensor

Tags: camera, sensors, tablet, tango

At a company I work for we're developing a 3D Reconstruction app that can be downloaded to common Android devices. In order for the reconstructions to work the best, we need to input the devices' camera sensor size (specifically the CCD width). Through the app's Play Store administration page we've seen several users using something called "Google ATAP Project Tanto Tablet (Yellowstone)". Can anyone help us know what sensor size does that tablet has? This would improve the reconstructions made on that device. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, Tango Yellowstone tablet uses a combined RGB and IR camera from OmniVision, OV4682 RGB IR. You can find more specifications here: 
http://www.ovt.com/products/sensor.php?id=145